# Flutter RealTime Online an Offline Using Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want best way to show in an app if the user is online or offline in Real time?

I have use **statefulWidget** State class with **WidgetsBindingObserver** but i can see some draw back in it like

1. if my data finished it will not update the collection in firebase.
2. if i off my data it will not update the Firebase collection
3. if i put the update in the **Inistate** of the app to update the collection status, and if i have a new user and the user load the app, it will it give error...
   like this:

> ```
>  update(String state) {
>     firestore
>         .collection('users')
>         .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
>         .update({'active': state});
>   }
>
>   @override
>   void initState() {
>     WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
>     super.initState();
>     update('Online');
>   }
> ```

the code above give error if a new user load the app...

thanks for helping...

Comment: For an online/offline solution I would suggest you to use a timestamp to store instead of online / offline strings. This would allow you to handle the case if the user closes the app and you can't handle it then anymore. Then the timestamp would be much better, since you can check no one is longer than an hour active and show all other users, that this person is not online anymore.

Comment: i dont understand using timestamp.. can you give me a sample code

Comment: Consider https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for your comment, i have read through it. Thanks